# $A / B$ set operation in boolean logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

When doing $A / B$ set operation, is there an equavalency in boolean logic? For instance A union B is the equivalent to $A ∨ B$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean ***A/B***, where ***A/B***={x|x∈**A** ∧ x∉**B**}. If that is what you mean, then I don't believe there is an exact Boolean correspondence. However, notice when we say ***A∪B***={x|x∈**A** v x∈**B**}, there is a Boolean functor "or" in the set-builder notation of ***A∪B***, and element-hood does not vary from set ***A*** to set ***B***. On the other hand, looking back at ***A/B***, we see that the definition of the set is dependent not only on the functor, but also on the concept of element-hood.

---

### Edit:

That said, Some have argue that there is a Boolean counterpart for set difference. That is, $(A \land \lnot B)$. However, it boils down to personal preference; or, perhaps if it there is any pragmatic value in treating it as such.

Also, for unions and intersections we can De Morgan distribute them like conjunction and disjunction; however, for difference we can do no such thing.

Comment: I disagree; the use of the "is element of" predicate is not really that key in the definition of $A \backslash B$ (I've seen this notation more often than $A / B$, which is usually used to denote a quotient group). In fact, a sensible interpretation of $A \backslash B$ in Boolean logic would be $A \wedge \neg B$. This fits well with the set-theoretic definition, because we write $A \backslash B$ to mean the set of elements in $A$ *and not* in $B$.

Comment: @Sambo I understand where you are coming from. In fact that was my initial knee jerk response. Consider A∩B is generally taken as A ∧ B. Similarly, A∪B is considered A v B and when you analyze the set builder definition of union and intersection you see in both, union and intersection, element-hood is unchanged. However,  when you look at A/B, element-hood does play a role. Therefore it would be a gross misattribution to disregard it when looking for its Boolean counterpart. Regardless, That was my personal two cents. Boolean correspondence doesn't really matter anyways, it is just heuristic.

Comment: It kind of does matter for bitvectors in computers. I do agree with Sambo though. If you were performing this operation, the equivalence would be A and not B

Comment: @Bertrand I don't see why "element-hood" plays a role in $A \backslash B$ and not $A \cap B$. Can you elaborate further? I just see $A \backslash B = \{x | (x \in A) \wedge \neg (x \in B) \}$

Comment: @Sambo for a intersection we can say $x\in (A \land B)$; for Union we can say $x \in (A \lor B)$. However, for difference we can not do the same. That is, $x \in (A \lnot B)$, which can further be developed to $x \in A \land x\in \lnot B)$. But if you notice, $x\in \lnot B$ is not a positive statement. That is, we can not usefully utilize it; that is not to say that negative statement are useless in general. Now, as you can see, I am of the view that $A\B$ does not have a Boolean correspondence or the sole reason of heuristic. That said, it is not set in stone.